# Cache Coherency Issues when Accessing Userspace Memory from DMA

Tags: caching, fpga, dma

I am trying to make a block of memory allocated in Linux userspace accessible over PCIe by a DMA core in a FPGA Board.

What I do so far is allocate memory with **posix_memalign()** in a userspace application and then pass its pointer to my kernel driver.

In my kernel driver I use the **get_user_pages()** in order to get the list of pages from the userspace memory.
The code below represents the next steps I follow to create a scatter/gather list:

```
merged_entries = get_user_pages(current, current->mm, (unsigned long)buffer, entries, 1, 1, page_array, vma_array /*NULL*/);


if(merged_entries)
{

    for(repeat = 0; repeat < merged_entries; repeat++)
    {
        (u32 *)kmap(page_array[repeat]);
    }       

    sg_init_table(scatter_list_array, merged_entries);

    for(repeat = 0; repeat < merged_entries; repeat++)
    {
        sg_set_page(&scatter_list_array[repeat], page_array[repeat], 4096, 0);

    }

    dma_buffers = pci_map_sg(dev, scatter_list_array, merged_entries, PCI_DMA_BIDIRECTIONAL);


    for(repeat = 0; repeat < dma_buffers; repeat++)
    {
        dma_address_array[repeat] = sg_dma_address(&scatter_list_array[repeat]);
        dma_buffers_length_array[repeat] = sg_dma_len(&scatter_list_array[repeat]);

    }
```

Once I get the scatter/gather list I give it to the DMA.

In order to test if it operates correctly I write data from the userspace application to my userspace allocated memory.
Then I force the DMA to write different data at the same allocated memory but the application keeps reading the same data as before the DMA transfer.

What I understand, supposing that the DMA transfer is successful, is that the application writes data to the cache.
When it comes to read data back it keeps reading from the cache, thus, it is not aware for the data that are written by the DMA in my allocated memory block.

I believe that, if I am correct, I face a cache coherency issue.

What I was suggested is that I should flush the range of cache where the data is written and then invalidate the same range of cache.

I tried several functions, such as  **flush_cache_range()**, **flush_cache_all()**, **cleancache_invalidate_page()** and **dma_sync_sg_for_cpu**.

Unfortunately, none of them worked as I expected.

Are there any suggestions to solve my problem?

Is there any memory allocator function (in userspace) such as **posix_memalign()** **and malloc()** that is uncacheable?

Could this not be a cache coherency issue?

I have have searched a lot so far but it is not very clear to me what I might do wrong.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the host processor?